# How to get list aws snapshot filtered by description string

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, aws-ebs

How to retrieve snapshot list filtering by description of snapshot with a common string through AWS-SDK(Ruby).

Here is ex

```
 1. snapshot-id        description
 2. 1xxvfs         snapdesp100
 3. 2xxhgso        snapdesp150
 4. 3##sfsj        snapdesp240
```

I want to filter with description "snapdesp1" and the output need like below.
output :

```
 1. 1xxvfs
 2. 2xxhgso
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, please share the Ruby (or other) code that you've written so far and explain where it's going wrong so someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

The `DescribeSnapshots()` command can filter on `description`, but I don't think it will accept wildcards.

You should simply call `DescribeSnapshots()` to retrieve a complete list of snapshots, then filter the results within your Ruby code.